How to stop automatic login to Google Play Games in Unity
I want the players to have the option to log into their account in my game via google play but I only want it to happen if they choose it (by pressing a button). Now what happens is that as soon as my game is opened with a player then google play immediately connects the player to his account through google play, I don't want this to happen.
here is the code:

    public void SingIn()
    {
        PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.Authenticate(ProcessAuthentication);
    }

    internal void ProcessAuthentication(SignInStatus status)
    {
        if (status == SignInStatus.Success)
        {
            PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.RequestServerSideAccess(false, ProcessServerAuthCode);
        }
    }

    private void ProcessServerAuthCode(string serverAuthCode)
    {
        Debug.Log("Server Auth Code: " + serverAuthCode);

        var request = new LoginWithGooglePlayGamesServicesRequest
        {
            ServerAuthCode = serverAuthCode,
            CreateAccount = true,
            TitleId = PlayFabSettings.TitleId
        };

        PlayFabClientAPI.LoginWithGooglePlayGamesServices(request, OnLoginWithGooglePlayGamesServicesSuccess, OnLoginWithGooglePlayGamesServicesFailure);
    }

    private void OnLoginWithGooglePlayGamesServicesSuccess(LoginResult result)
    {
        Debug.Log("PF Login Success LoginWithGooglePlayGamesServices");

        string displayName = PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.GetUserDisplayName();

        var request = new UpdateUserTitleDisplayNameRequest
        {
            DisplayName = displayName
        };
        
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("UserName", displayName);

        PlayFabClientAPI.UpdateUserTitleDisplayName(request, 
            onSuccess => Debug.Log("Display name updated successfully"),
            onError => Debug.LogError("Error updating display name: " + onError.GenerateErrorReport())
        );

        SceneManager.LoadScene("Home");
    }

    private void OnLoginWithGooglePlayGamesServicesFailure(PlayFabError error)
    {
        Debug.Log("PF Login Failure LoginWithGooglePlayGamesServices: " + error.GenerateErrorReport());
    }
    


stop auto logging into Google Play in Unity

Where are you calling SingIn? Why can't you just call that behind a button press?

I do call it by pressing a button, but even without pressing the button, Google Play simply connects the players to their accounts automatically

I would suggest steping through your code and making sure that is the case. Functions to connect to play will not execute unless they are being called, there's no magic happening here.
